# Spyder requires jedi>=0.10 but installs jedi==0.90

Tags: pip, ipython, spyder

(Working in ubuntu 17.04, dunno if that makes any difference) Afer encountering this problem in pip3: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4216 I resorted to using the *dev* 10.0.0 version. Then, after upgradding all packages - I see that I cannot open spyder because it requires jedi>= 10.0:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2999, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2901, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 824, in setup
    self.findinfiles = FindInFiles(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/findinfiles.py", line 52, in __init__
    include = self.include_patterns()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/findinfiles.py", line 105, in include_patterns
    for ext in get_edit_extensions():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/config/utils.py", line 140, in get_edit_extensions
    edit_filetypes = get_edit_filetypes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/config/utils.py", line 118, in get_edit_filetypes
    pygments_exts = _get_pygments_extensions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/config/utils.py", line 85, in _get_pygments_extensions
    for lx in lexers.get_all_lexers():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/__init__.py", line 53, in get_all_lexers
    for lexer in find_plugin_lexers():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygments/plugin.py", line 53, in find_plugin_lexers
    yield entrypoint.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2301, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 859, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (jedi 0.9.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('jedi>=0.10'))
```

Then, if I upgrade jedi to any version >= 0.10, Spyder pops up a message saying: `You have missing dependencies! jedi =0.9.0: 0.10.2 (NOK)` but it opens, without ipython.

Where do i go from here? Internal console in spyder tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'banner'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtconsole/base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch
    handler(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtconsole/jupyter_widget.py", line 296, in _handle_kernel_info_reply
    super(JupyterWidget, self)._started_channels()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtconsole/frontend_widget.py", line 617, in _started_channels
    self.reset(clear=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtconsole/frontend_widget.py", line 661, in reset
    self._append_plain_text(self.banner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/ipythonconsole/shell.py", line 280, in _banner_default
    return self.long_banner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/widgets/ipythonconsole/shell.py", line 91, in long_banner
    from IPython.core.usage import quick_guide
ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'
```

and I didn't find any resources to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'quick_guide'
```

...was reported at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4170 and and fixed at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/4208 and released in version [3.1.4](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.1.4)

Type

```
pip3 install --upgrade spyder
```

to fix this issue.